# Why does the rjust method leave a string unchanged?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have 2 codes snippets in Python 3:

```
print(b'3'.rjust(4, b'0'))

b'0003'
```

```
length = str(len("str")).encode() # length as bytes
length.rjust(4, b'0') # trying to pad length
print(length)

b'3'
```

As I understand it, both should produce the same result as the first snippet. Why does the second snippet not work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length.rjust` returns a new string.  Strings in Python cannot be modified in place.  Try:

```
length = length.rjust(4, b'0')
```